# Class to store multiple comparators

Tags: java, class, sorting, nested, comparator

I have a task to sort files (list of files), dependng on user input by name, size, date modified, size, type, and other types of conditions can be added in future.

So if user inputs "dir /sort=esdn" (extension, size, date, name)
That means sort by extension, where program can't decide sort by size...

I thougth it would be messy to have all those comparators in same class or as lambda expressions, so i had idea of creating a new clas where all comparisons code would be

```
public class Comparisons {

    public class Ext implements Comparator<File> {
        ...
    }

    public class Size implements Comparator<File> {
        ...
    }

    public class Date implements Comparator<File> {
        ...
    }

    public class Name implements Comparator<File> {
        ...
    }

    public class Type implements Comparator<File> {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I have idea how to run it and all, but I can't seem to find a way to create new inner class without creating outer class first. It seems to me that Java would have something like that as it foucuses a lot on sytax sugar, best alterntative would be new package.

Rest of the code would be recursive function that sorts by first letter

```
private boolean sort(String substring, List<File> fin) {
        Comparator<File> k = null;

        char in = substring.toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        switch (in) {
        case n:
            k = Comparisons.new Name();
            break;
        case e:
            k = Comparisons.new Ext();
            break;
        case s:
            k = Comparisons.new Size();
            break;
        case d:
            k = Comparisons.new Date();
            break;
        case t:
            k = Comparisons.new Type();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    ...
    }
```

I know this doesn't work but that's the general idea of what I want to achieve.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I thought it would be messy to have all those comparators in same class or as lambda expressions" - What is messy about that? The lambda route seems to be the best option, especially if you use method references.

Comment: Code Snippets are for runnable web language examples. Use the Code Sample `{ }` button instead.

Comment: I thought it would be better for code reusability, and adding a bunch of classes or methods at the end feels messy to me because they are clearly gruped and do similar tasks, and just adding to end doesn't seem too good, but that might just be me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `enum`:

```
public enum FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    DateComparator {

        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

    },
    SizeComparator {

        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

    },

    NameComparator {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Each element in the `enum` can have its own version of the `compare` method and you won't need to create any classes, but still you can use it like normal class:

```
Comparator<File> comp = FileComparator.NameComparator;
//use the comparator
```